# How to cancel load or change page for jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile, load

I want cancel cancel load or change page in pagebeforecreate event for jquery mobile.
what jquery mobile's function can do it?

Answer (score 2):

If possible for your specific use case, consider using the `pagechange`event instead of the `pagebeforecreate`. You can prevent the ajax request in the first place instead of using the ajax request's `abort()` method. The code would look like this:

```js
$(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function(e, data) {
   // check data.toPage attribute here and decide if the pagechange should be canceled
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me perfectly.

```
$.mobile.changePage( "../alerts/confirm.html", {

    transition: "pop",

    reverse: false,

});
```